# Who should call RPC function while hit by a bullet

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, photon

My question is simple.

Im creating top down 2D shooter game via PUN2 Free in Unity.
I want to synchronize collisions through network, to avoid lags inaccuracy.
A player is firing a bullet and it hits enemy. I want players to know about all bullets hits(to reduce health, get kill, etc.).

Should I call RPC_Hit() from shooter to other players to inform about actual hit or it would be more wise to call RPC_Hit() from hurt player to other players in game.

Im asking in terms of better synchronization, I guess lags will happen, so in my oppinion it would be better to call RPC function from player which got hit, but then if I would need to send callback only to shooter(for example, to let him now how many dmg he did) it would be hard, cause I can only send RPC to "MasterClient,All,Others".

This bothers me.
I can not find any informations about this.

In same moment the Player1 and Player2 view differs cause of Lag
[image]

Comment: I don't know Photon but usually you send a RPC only from the server to all clients. Afaik there is no direct way for sending data directly between different clients without passing the server so: client -> inform server -> inform all clients

Comment: If i understand Photon well, it automatically send every RPC called from client to server and other clients.

Comment: I just want to know if is technically better to do :

a)
Player1 bullet hits Player2, Player1 call enemyHit.RPC_TakeDamage() to other players.

b)
Player1 bullet hits Player2. Player2 calls RPC_GotHit() to all players.

Comment: Hm would this tequnically make a big difference? Depends maybe what else should happen. Of only e.g. health is reduced than maybe b); if additionally adding points for player1 maybe more like a)?

Comment: I did an update, maybe now this will make things clear.
This may be a stupid unprofessional question, but i just want to make sure.

Comment: After your image it seems like the issue is actually that the bullet collision is only being detected on player1? In this case it's clear which way to go, right? Maybe it's me who isn't getting it ;) as said I don't know photon at all ^^

Comment: I think i got it, thanks anyway! :)

Comment: Best solutions are those you figure out on your own ;) so congrats